# Is it better practice to work with information within a file / folder or to load that information first?

Tags: c#

I have a folder of files and a spreadsheet with a list of file names. I need to go through each file in the folder and see if that file name exists on the spreadsheet. It seems I can either load all the information (file names and spreadsheet list) into lists and then search from there or I can just loop through the files, get the name as I go, then look through the spreadsheet itself.

As far as I can tell, the benefit to loading them first is that it may make the search code a bit cleaner, but if there are too many files it would be redundant and slower. Working directly with the files and spreadsheet would negate that intermediate step, but the search code would be a little bit messier.

Is there any other clear trade off that I am missing? Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful as comparing two lists results in a **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** problem. This means that if you have 20 files, you will have to make 20 * 20 = 400 comparisons.

Therefore I suggest putting the filenames from the spreadsheet into a `HashSet<string>`. It has a constant access time of **O(1)**. This reduces your problem to a **O(n)** problem.

```
// Gather the file names from the spreadsheet and insert them in a HashSet.
// (This is just simulated here.)
var fileNamesOnSpreadsheet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    "filename 1", "filename 2", "filename 3", "another filename"
};

string folder = @"C:\Data";
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder)) {
    if (fileNamesOnSpreadsheet.Contains(file)) {
        // file found in spreadsheet
    } else {
        // file missing from spreadsheet
    }
}
```

Note that `Directory.EnumerateFiles` get the filenames including their paths an extensions. If you have the bare filenames in the spreadsheet, you can remove the path with

```
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(file);
```

You can also remove the extension with

```
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
```

Note that this solution reads the files from the folder only once and gets the file names from the spreadsheet only once. Reading information from file system is time-consuming and extracting information form the spreadsheet as well.

`Directory.EnumerateFiles` does not even store the filenames in a collection but instead delivers them continuously as the foreach-loop progresses.

So, this solution is very efficient.

See also:

- [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Big O notation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will use this solution. The number of files isn't really big enough for performance to be critical, but I just wanted some ideas on how to go about it if performance becomes critical in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For small numbers of names and a single search it takes so little time that optimizing the code is probably not worth it and you can do whatever is easiest for you.

For the sheet, it could make sense to load the names into a list* because you will search the list N times (once per file) and searching the list will be faster than searching the sheet.  It might also make sense to have the list sorted so searches take log N time instead of N

- as @JonathanWillcock1 notes, other in-memory data structures such as a dictionary might work even better, hiding the details of sorting and searching from you and making your code cleaner.

For the file names you only look at each name one once so iterating through a directory listing function is all that you need and copying it to a list would double the work.

Comment: I would suggest loading the names from the spreadsheet into a `Dictionary` as it makes searching considerably faster than a `List`, particularly if there are many elements.

Comment: Unfortunately the spreadsheet isn't guaranteed to be sorted so I would have the added complexity of sorting the list.